# How to solve InstanceCountViolation for 2 activities calling each other with back button?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activities:

- Activity A: showing a list of menu items with price. Click on an item will open Activity B
- Activity B: edit price for the clicked item. Click "Done" will go back to Activity A

The use case is simple and as the following:

1. launching Activity B from Activity A => there is no issue
2. click "Done" or back button in B and get back to A => there is no issue
3. launching Activity B from Activity A again => there is no issue
4. click "Done" or back button in B and get back to A => crash with error:

```
2021-02-26 16:21:42.107 13116-13116/? D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.InstanceCountViolation: class package.editPriceActivity; instances=2; limit=1
at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

I think when clicking the "Done" button and going back, Activity B should be automatically killed? (I also tried calling `finish()` but the error is still there.

What am I doing wrong here? How is such an event designed in a common way when users need to go back and forth between activities but avoid the violation?

Comment: show me your code

Comment: the code is important here, if you can't share the code look into launch modes.